# joining R data frames that are composed of lists : need to convert data frame of lists to data frame of vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a few R data frames, between which I need to do a couple of `join` operations using `dplyr`. However, this fails with the following error message `Can't join on 'id.parcours' x 'id.parcours' because of incompatible types (list / list)`.

The columns of my data.frames are lists, they have been read using `fromJSON` from csv.

I guess I should simply convert convert a data frame where columns are lists to a data frame where columns are vectors, but I can't find a very concise way to do that. All lists in a data frame are the same length. Thx!

Comment: Did you try `dplyr::unnest()`? Else, please post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all lists are same length, you can use `dplyr::unnest()`. At least it works in this minimal example:

```
dplyr::unnest(tibble::tibble(a = list(letters), b = list(LETTERS)))
```

Else, please provide sample data.